# How does running a test in PyCharm result in an "Model class doesn't declare an explicit app_label" error?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, testing, pycharm

I'm using Django, Python 3.7, and PyCharm 2018.3.5.  I'm trying to run a test in PyCharm by right-clicking on the test name and selecting, "Run Test: 'test name'".  This results in the following error

```
RuntimeError: Model class appname.models.Label doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

This is the model in question, at the top of my models.py file ...

```
class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name",)
```

What is very odd is if I run the tests outside of PyCharm (e.g. at a terminal command prompt using "python manage.py test"), everything runs fine.  So the problem would seem to be some misconfiguration with PyCharm.  I'm unclear how to attack the problem further.  Below is my project directory structure ...

```
appname
    __init__.py
    __pycache__
    admin.py
    apps.py
    fixtures
    management
    migrations
    models.py
    services.py
    static
    templates
    tests.py
    views.py
manage.py
templates
venv
appname_project
```

**Edit:** I edited my environment variables to be the following

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT=true
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=appname_project.settings
```

THis is because my settings files are environment specific, so the path to my dev one is

```
appname_project/settings/dev.py
```

but even adding the above results in the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyCharm uses its own `test_runner` when builtin option for running tests is used. Most of the time it is not able find `settings.py` file. So you have to explicitly define `settings` file.

1. Go on top right corner and select Edit Configurations from run
   configurations menu.
2. Select particular confifuration for running
   your test.
3. Click on Environment variables. Add
   `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` with `YOUR_PROJECT.settings` (or path to
   whichever settings file your are using) as value.
4. Save and run
   again.

It should work now.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question to include the exact environment variables I'm using per what you instructed.  Unfortunately, even after saving those variables and re-running the test, I get the same error.

Comment: Is settings a package (directory with `__init__.py` file) inside `appname_project`? You should add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=appname_project.settings.dev`

Comment: Hi, No, there was no "__init__.py" file in the "settings" folder, but when I changed the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to what you suggest it works.  So perhaps I should ask this as a different question, but is there somewhere I can put these variables so that I don't have to create these environemnt vars for every test I run?

Comment: Well there is another way for specifying settings file in PyCharm. Go to File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Django. There you will see option for specifying settings file. Click on that, and locate your settings file. Now this should work for every test.

Comment: The official django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial05/ needs to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings because it locates /mysite/settings.py . You saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was different.

PyCharm does have its own `test_runner` like @Nafees Anwar said, and in my case it *silenced the real error*, and spit this `doesn't declare an explicit app_label` nonsense.

In my case the real reason, I had `SECRET_KEY` set to `None` (I wanted to be explicit, and dever assign default values).

To validate **your** real error, instead of running tests, try running `manage.py` from PyCharm. It will then print your real error.

Comment: This ended up being the case with me since we were doing fancy things to load secrets from environment variables which was being circumvented due to the pycharm test runner